# Databinding and BaseObserver - Android MVVM

Tags: kotlin, observer-pattern, android-databinding

I have a textfield which is databound to a view model like the xml here and I want the UI to update the txtProvider field on click of the cardView.
How should I notify the change to the view from my viewmodel?

```
<layout xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable name="viewmodel"        
              type="io.leapingwolf.myapp.viewmodel.MyViewModel"/>
   <variable
    name="myModel"
    type="io.leapingwolf.myapp.models.MyModel"/>
</data>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:onClick="@{viewmodel.onClickModel}">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtProvider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="@{myModel.provider}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

In MyViewModel(which extends BaseObserver class), I have

```
fun onClickModel() : View.OnClickListener {
        val viewOnClick = View.OnClickListener { v ->
                                myModel!!.provider = "name changed"
                                notifyPropertyChanged(BR.myModel)
                                Toast.makeText(context,"clicked:" + myModel!!.provider , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
                                return viewOnClick
        }
```

My data class :

```
data class MyModel(
        val type: String?,
        var  provider: String? 
) : AutoParcelable
```

Comment: How does your text field look like?

Comment: The txtProvider in the layout file is the text field.

Comment: So you don't have a variable or property for the text in your viewmodel...?

Comment: I thought about it and made some changes to the code. I created a variable for the model in the layout file and bound the property to the text field. Then, I change the property value in onClickModel and call notifyPropertyChanged. Yet the changes to the property value are not propogated to the UI. Any pointers please

Comment: Please, post your code. We are no wizards and only can guess what is going wrong.

Comment: I have bound the value of "provider" property to the TextView in the layout file android:text="@{myModel.provider}" . On initial load, I see the value in the textfield.So, the binding works. When I click on the card view, i change the value of the property on line -> myModel!!.provider = "name changed" and call notifyPropertyChanged(BR.myModel). I am expecting the "name changed" to show up in the textview now. I have posted the relevant code block. Could you specify which code you want to see.

Comment: Normally, you don't need to call `notifyPropertyChanged`in your code (except in the model where you declare the setter). It is important to know how the `provider` is declared - is it a string, a observablefield, how do the setters and getters look like.

Comment: My model is a data class that has Provider as string. Added it to the question above. Only my viewmodel extends BaseObservable so notifyPropertyChanged is not available in the data class

Answer (score 2):

I got it working in Kotlin using the @Bindable in the viewmodel like below.Took me a while to understand how to use @Bindable in Kotlin syntax. The property BR.provider was not getting generated till i got the @Bindable syntax right.

```
fun onClickModel(): View.OnClickListener {
    val viewOnClick = View.OnClickListener {
        route!!.provider = "name changed"
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.provider)
    }
    return viewOnClick
}

val provider: String
    @Bindable
    get() {
        Log.d("Utils", "get property")
        return route!!.provider!!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a java syntax, because I'm not that fluent with kotlin:

You need to declare your `MyModel` or the `provider` with `DataBinding` to enable the binding. Use a `@Bindable` on getter, and call `notifyPropertyChanged`in the setter:

```
@Bindable
public String getProvider() {
    return this.provider;
}

public void setProvider(String provider) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.provider);
}
```

or make your `MyModel` extend `BaseObservable`, or since you have a viewmodel, create a `ObservableField<String>` or even a `ObservableField<MyModel>`:

```
//in your viewmodel:
private ObservableField<MyModel> modelField = new ObservableField<MyModel>();
```

Set the value in the constructor of your viewmodel, create a getter and reference this in your `xml`.

Comment: I got it working in Kotlin using the @Bindable in the viewmodel like

Answer (score 1):

In your MyModel.kt file

```
class MyModel(
        @get:Bindable
        var provider: String = ""
) : BaseObservable() {
    fun updateText(str:String){
        provider = str
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.counter)
    }
}
```

and then in your layout.xml

```
android:onClick="@{() -> myModel.updateText(`YOUR TEXT`)}"
```

`Rebuild` your project if you cannot get `BR.counter` autocomplete working

Answer (score 0):

It might be more of a kotlin issue. When I initialise the provider String as ObservableField as

```
var provider = ObservableField<String>()
init{
    provider = route.provider as ObservableField<String>
}
```

I get an error at runtime
java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.databinding.ObservableField

I will try posting it on the kotlin discussion site and seek some answers.